# Download json files of all resources in an azure resource group using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Hello I'm trying to download all of azure resources in a specific prompted resource group using powershell into json format but it seems like each resource has specific commands that's making it difficult to parse through as a list. These files are being taken to compare after deployments to validate changes. Here is the current version of the script I'm working with. Each different resource type is likely using a different api version.

I have also considered using a version with azcopy from azure.resources.com I don't have a strong preference. The current files are being manually copied from azure.resources.com.

```
# Prompt the user for the Azure resource group name
$resourceGroup = Read-Host "Enter the Azure resource group name"

# Prompt the user to specify "old" or "new" for the file path
$fileSuffix = Read-Host "Do you want to append 'old' or 'new' to the file path?"

# Ensure the user provided a valid suffix
if ($fileSuffix -notin "old", "new") {
    Write-Host "Invalid file suffix. Please enter 'old' or 'new'."
    return
}

# Define the folder where you want to save the JSON files
$folderName = $resourceGroup

# Create the folder if it doesn't exist
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $folderName -PathType Container)) {
    New-Item -Path $folderName -ItemType Directory
}

# Get all resources in the specified resource group
$resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup

if ($resources) {
    foreach ($resource in $resources) {
        # Extract the resource provider information
        $providerNamespace = $resource.ResourceProviderNamespace
        $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType
        $apiVersion = $resource.ApiVersion
        $resourceName = $resource.Name

        # Construct the file path with the specified suffix
        $filePath = "$folderName\$providerNamespace\$resourceType\$fileSuffix\$resourceName-$apiVersion.json"

        # Create the provider namespace, resource type, and suffix folders if they don't exist
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$folderName\$providerNamespace\$resourceType\$fileSuffix" -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path "$folderName\$providerNamespace\$resourceType\$fileSuffix" -ItemType Directory -Force
        }

        # Get the resource JSON using Azure CLI and save it to the constructed file path
        az resource show --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $resourceName --resource-type $resourceType --api-version $apiVersion --query '{Name:name, Properties:properties}' --output json | Set-Content -Path $filePath

        # Check if the resource was found and downloaded successfully
        if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) {
            Write-Host "Resource JSON downloaded successfully to $filePath"
        } else {
            Write-Host "Failed to download resource JSON for resource $resourceName"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "No resources found in resource group '$resourceGroup'"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Download json files of all resources in an azure resource group using Powershell?

Here is the updated `Power shell` script to download `Json` files of all resources in an azure resource.

```
# Define the output directory
$outputDirectory = "C:\Venkat\ResourceGroup resource"  

# Specify the Azure resource group
$resourceGroupName = "Resource-Group"

# Get the resources in the resource group
$resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Loop through each resource and save its JSON representation to a file
foreach ($resource in $resources) {
    $resourceName = $resource.Name
    $resourceType = $resource.ResourceType

    # Define the output JSON file path
    $outputFilePath = Join-Path -Path $outputDirectory -ChildPath "$resourceType-$resourceName.json"

    # Create the directory path if it doesn't exist
    $outputDirectoryPath = Split-Path -Path $outputFilePath
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $outputDirectoryPath -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $outputDirectoryPath -ItemType Directory
    }

    # Export the resource to a JSON file
    $resource | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Once the `PowerShell` script is run, `JSON` files of all resources in the `resource group` are downloaded.

[image]